# Quorum Smart Contract Performance Azure Blockchain Serivce

Tags: solidity, quorum, permissioned-chain, blockchain-as-a-service, azure

I wonder that how I can improve smart contract performance in Quorum.

Right now I have a smart contract which save supply chain information and we are using Azure Blockchain Service for Quorum. We have four validaor node for that.

Rigth now our TPS avarage is 1, yes we just send 50 transaction per minute and this is very slow against high performance which is written in offical document.

By the way I don't sure that how smart contract performance affect TPS.

If you have any information, it can be helpfull really to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Without details, it would be hard to suggest what an issue may be. Best place to get Quorum specific advice is on our slack tho, so please stop by so we could chat in detail: http://bit.ly/quorum-slack. Thanks!